# How to get hyperlink address from a cell in excel by using java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jxl

I know how to use JavaExcelApi (jxl) or Apache POI to read string information of a cell in an excel file by writing some java code. But now I got a problem:

A cell contains a string with a hyperlink on it. I can read the string in this cell, but I don't know how to read the hyperlink address through java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [Cell.getHyperlink()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getHyperlink%28%29), which returns either null (cell has no hyperlink) or a [Hyperlink object](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Hyperlink.html)

If you wanted to fetch the hyperlink URL of cell B2 of test.xls, you'd do something like:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("test.xls"));
Sheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Row r2 = s.getRow(1); // Rows in POI are 0 based
Cell cB2 = r2.getCell(1); // Cells are 0 based

Hyperlink h = cB2.getHyperlink();
if (h == null) {
   System.err.println("Cell B2 didn't have a hyperlink!");
} else {
   System.out.println("B2 : " + h.getLabel() + " -> " + h.getAddress());
}
```