# Converting excel (.xslx) file to java with cell that has hyperlink text won't be recognized and result is cell with empty value

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

This is the code which iterate through the excel file and extract the value from the cells:

```
public static <R> List<R> readAdvancedStudentSearchFromCSV(String fileName, CSVParser<R> parser) throws IOException {
        List<R> rowsList = new ArrayList<>();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        //Create Workbook instance for xlsx/xls file input stream
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        if(fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith("xlsx")){
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        }

        int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("data");

        int rowCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=2; i<rowCount; i++){
            String cellValue = "";
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                try {
                    cellValue = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                    System.out.println(cellValue);
                }catch(NullPointerException e){
                    cellValue = "";
                }
                if(cellValue.equals("")){
                    line.append(" ").append(" ").append(",");
                }else {
                    line.append(" ").append(cellValue).append(",");
                }
            }
            String[] attributes = line.toString().split(",");
            R row = parser.toRow(attributes);
            rowsList.add(row);
        }

        //close file input stream
        fis.close();
        return rowsList;
    }
```

And this is how the excel file look like:
[image]

Problem:

When I reach cell No.7 (trying to get column named "Resume") with the value but I am getting empty string instead of getting the actual hypertextlink  (as string or as link it is not important).
I have tried to use *getHypertextLink* method from *Cell* class but this did not help as well.

I have looked at: [How to get hyperlink address from a cell in excel by using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987028/how-to-get-hyperlink-address-from-a-cell-in-excel-by-using-java)
which did not solve my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get hyperlink address from a cell in excel by using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987028/how-to-get-hyperlink-address-from-a-cell-in-excel-by-using-java)

Comment: Thank you @XtremeBaumer , I saw this solution and tried it and it did not give me any value.

Comment: `getHypertextLink` is not a valid method for [`Cell`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html)

Comment: Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j); sysOut(cell.toString()); Can you please try this one ?